# Formatting phone number in XSLT

Tags: xslt, replace, str-replace

I am having a phone number in my xml in this format like (515) 123456 and I need to have it like simple like 515123456. I used below code and it's throwing me an error

any idea how this can be done ?

```
 <xsl:value-of
                select="replace(replace(Mobile1, ') ', ''), '(', '')"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the `replace()` function is a regex pattern. Parentheses are special characters in regex, and must be escaped when used literally:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(Mobile1, '\) ', ''), '\(', '')"/>
```

Or use simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Mobile1, '() ', '' )"/>
```