# Issues with Replace function in XSL

Tags: xslt, replace, translate

I am having a string which contains all types of special characters like dot comma # () - space / \ and I used Replace function in below way and getting multiple errors. I used double quotes for comma '','' is it the right way to do ? Also getting issue with #

Example string is

```
#12/24 Dominic-Road,Villa(12)
```

This needs to be replaced as

```
1224DominicRoadVilla12
```

This is my expression so far:

```
select="replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace($string1, '\)', ''), '\(', ''), '\.', ''), '\-', ''), ' ', ''), '#', ''),'','','')"
```

But I got errors:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of replace()

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The current expression fails because of the `,'','','')` at the end, which do not correspond to any of the existing `replace` calls (i.e, you have three extra parameters, and an unmatched closing bracket). Note that as you are only replacing single characters you could also use `translate` and do `translate($string1, ')(.- #', '')`

Comment: As you have been told before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54143940/3016153

Comment: Note that, if you are getting the message `A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of replace()`, then this suggests an issue with how the variable `$string1` is defined. It is probably a sequence of more than one node. Can you edit your question to show a proper sample of your XML, and how `$string1` is defined? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your expression.
Replace your `xsl:value` with

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($string1, '[#\-,/() .]+', '')" />
```

This removes the mentioned special characters. If you need to exclude more special characters, add them to the second parameter.